# How to change vuforia video source with a custom camera

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I would like change source camera video by custom camera stream using Vuforia and Unity:

- Take the video stream from the camera (Android cam or Webcam)
- Improve contrast, brightness or other manually (for example through openCV) and add elements or another pattern that could be optimally recognized by Vuforia.
- Resend the modified video stream in Unity 3D and have it detected by Vuforia

It is possible ?
Is there another mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Vuforia takes its input directly from the camera and processes it - the maximum you can do is alter some of the camera settings (if you want to explore that, read about the Vuforia advanced camera API), but this is not enough for you according to your requirements.

Your only option if you must do processing on the input video is to handle the detection and tracking yourself without Vuforia (for example, using OpenCV), which is obviously not so easy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use any software for faking the camera like http://perfectfakewebcam.com/.
just prepare your video and feed it to the fake webcam software  and then from unity change vuforia **camera device** to  the fake webcam